# Achieving "punch out" text using Graphics2D

Tags: java, text, graphics2d

I'm trying to create a Punch Out effect on a Graphics2D render.

I have a rectangle colored black. Text Colored Red. I want to be able to set the color to 0x00FF0000 and have it "punch out" of the back ground.

```
    Graphics2D newG = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    newG.setColor(new Color(0x00,0x00,0x00,0xFF)); //255 Alpha
    newG.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);

    newG.setColor(new Color(0xFF,0x00,0x00,0x00)); //0 Alpha
    newG.drawString("Welcome", box.x ,box.y);
```

What I see is the text goes completely transparent against the back ground, but does not punch out.

What I see: [image: http://i.imgur.com/HYTe1.jpg]

What I expected to see : [image: http://i.imgur.com/YQwZk.jpg]

How can I achieve the 'punch out' effect using Graphics2D?

EDIT: Punch-Out Effect is like using a JLabel with a foreground set to 0x00FF0000, and a Back Ground 0xFF000000. it "cuts out"/"Punches Out" the text from the back ground. Also I do not want it to always punch out, only when alpha is 0.

EDIT2: Ive tried the sugested code below with identical results.

```
Rectangle stringBox = new Rectangle(x, y - fm.getHeight() + fm.getDescent(), fm.stringWidth(splitStr[i]), fm.getHeight());

TextLayout textLO = new TextLayout(splitStr[i], newG.getFont(), newG.getFontRenderContext());
 Shape sText = textLO.getOutline(newG.getTransform());      // The Shape of text
Path2D.Double shape = new Path2D.Double(stringBox);     // The rectangle
appendTextShape(shape, sText, newG.getTransform(), 0, 10);
newG.setColor(Color.black);
newG.fill(shape);
newG.setColor(new Color(0xFF, 0x00,0x00,0x00));
newG.drawString(splitStr[i], x, y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html

Properly setting up composition was the solution. SRC_IN was the composition i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like:

[image]

You need to get the outline `Shape` of text, then use `Path2D` to create a combined `Shape` to render:

```
Graphics2D g2d = ...;
TextLayout text = new TextLayout("Welcome", g2d.getFont(), g2d.getFontRenderContext());
Shape sText = text.getOutline(g2d.getTransform());      // The Shape of text
Path2D shape = new Path2D.Double(new Rectangle(200, 100));      // The rectangle
appendTextShape(shape, sText, g2d.getTransform(), 0, 10);   // combine the shape
g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2d.fill(rect);
```

And `appendTextShape` method is here:

```
public void appendTextShape (Path2D p, Shape s, AffineTransform t, int x, int y) {
    synchronized (s) {
        PathIterator pit = s.getPathIterator(t);
        float[] coords = new float[6];
        int c = 0;
        while (true) {
            pit.next();
            if (pit.isDone()) {
                break;
            }
            switch (pit.currentSegment(coords)) {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    p.moveTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1]);
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    if (c == 0) {
                        p.moveTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1]);
                    } else {
                        p.lineTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1]);
                    }
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                    if (c == 0) {
                        p.moveTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1]);
                    } else {
                        p.quadTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1], x + coords[2], y + coords[3]);
                    }
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                    if (c == 0) {
                        p.moveTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1]);
                    } else {
                        p.curveTo(x + coords[0], y + coords[1], x + coords[2], y + coords[3], x + coords[4], y + coords[5]);
                    }
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    p.closePath();
                    break;
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you using Path2D like that? Its abstract for Java 7u11

Comment: Looks like you need Path2D.double(Shape)

Comment: Also it appears I'm getting the same exact result even with this implementation.

Comment: @meriley And with this implementation, you are getting the text part "transparent" to the background, like it is "punched out"

Answer (score 0):

Your `appendTextShape` method is working.

However, it is already implemented in the consrtuctor of `Path2D`, like this:

```
Path2D path = new Path2D.Double(shape, affineTransform);
```